# Authors in proceeding are dominated by one university

Tags: conference, ieee

Recently I want to submit my manuscript to a conference. The accepted papers in this conference will be published in IEEE Xplore, so I thought this conference is reputable. But after I checked the last two years published proceeding (2021 is their 10th), more than 60% of the accepted papers authors are from one university (which is the host of the conference)

As I'm new in academia (as junior lecturer), I'm not sure is this normal and acceptable (the 60%), or is it a sign that the conference not reputable?

Comment: Is this maybe a really niche research area with few people working on it outside a group at that university?

Comment: I assume that if IEEE is a sponsor, then it is pretty reputable.

Comment: Not everyone likes travelling for work.  Even among people who do like travelling for work, not everyone has enough control over their own schedule (particularly when it comes to undergraduate teaching) to travel to conferences.  Even among people who like travelling and have control of their own schedules, not everyone has a budget to cover travel expenses.  Any of these might lead people disproportionately to submit to conferences hosted at their home university.  (I think the choices that OP observes happened pre-pandemic, so I won't put forward health risks as an additional explanation.)

Comment: There are plenty of small regional conferences out there, so it may well be reputable albeit dominated by the host institution. 10 years seems a reasonable track record.

Comment: @Peter No, the conference is about IT and have a wide coverage of topics, the total number of papers accepted reached 100 papers

Comment: It might be the easiest way for the organizers to motivate some more people to attend by giving discounts etc. to local researchers. And wouldn't you apply for a decent local conference? I would with 100% certainty, nothing wrong with that. The probability to go for a specific conference somewhere else is definitely lower.

Answer (score 1):

Conference reputation is essentially the experiences of the people who have attended the conference.  You have established that only a narrow group of people have attended.  So you know that the conference has an exceptionally narrow reputation.

I would not attend such a conference.

Proceedings for conferences during the COVID-19 pandemic should be disregarded as atypical.